# Tearing with tv and projector

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, hdmi, video-playback, screen-tearing

I hope you can help me with, I recently bought a projector but I have a problem.

When I connect it via HDMI to my notebook I get tearing on both screens when I play some videos with scenes with a lot of movement.

The problem of both devices is like these images:

Notebook:

[image: https://postimg.org/image/fhdtbvdbb/]

Projector (taken by me):

[image: https://postimg.org/image/3t5zcicfr/]

I tested the videos without connecting the projector and works fine, the problems starts when I plug the projector via HDMI.

This are my notebook specs:

```
Core i5 560m  
4gb ram  
Geforce 310m  
SSD 120gb  
hard disk 500gb  
Windows 10
```

The players tested: MPC-HC x64, VLC

Anyone can help me to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the proyector disable V-Sync, creating tearing. You can enable "High Performance" energy profile and also you can check NVIDIA graphic software incluided with drivers and search for a option like "Force V-Sync".

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it was projector's problem, i was unable to fix it.